# Special properties of matrices of rank r, where any r lines are linearily independent

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $M$ be a square complex-valued $n \times n$ matrix of rank r ($r < n$). Suppose that any r lines are linearly independent.

1) Do such matrices exist? They exist for rank 0, and trivially for rank 1, but I haven't been able to find non trivial examples.

2) Does this imply that any r columns are linearly independent?

Also, any such documentation would be helpful.

(Motivation: I'm trying to solve the following problem: find all $n \times n$ complex-valued matrices A with rank $< n$ such that $rank(AB) = rank(BA)$ for any $B$ that is $n\times n$. I have been able to show that $A$ must have the property discussed above.)

Answer (score 1):

By "lines" I assume you mean rows.

If $r$ rows of matrix $M$ are linearly dependent, it means there is a nonzero row vector $v$ with at most $r$ nonzero entries such that $v M = 0$.  Now if $M$ has rank $r$, the space $N$ of row vectors $v$ such that $vM =0$ (the left null space of $M$) has dimension $n-r$.  For a given subset $S$ of $[1\ldots n]$ with cardinality $r$, the space $R_S$ of row vectors whose nonzero entries are restricted to positions in $S$ has dimension $r$, so "generically" its intersection with
$N$ will be $\{0\}$.    Thus a randomly chosen matrix $M$ of rank $r$ will have the desired property with probability $1$.

It's not equivalent to the same property for columns, but again both will be true generically.